# Como eu faço para meu bot reconhecer que o usúario mandou uma imagem?

Tags: javascript, imagem

Estou fazendo um bot no Discord, e uma das funções que eu quero nele é a seguinte:
Eu quero que meu bot ao receber uma imagem enviada por um usuário edite ela e retorne como um meme. A partir é claro de um comando específico. Em questão da edição em si eu já fiz, utilizei o npm jimp que edita imagens por js, qualquer imagem dentro da minha pasta que coloco como variável vai ser editada e respondida pelo usuário, mas eu quero que a imagem editada seja uma da escolha do usuário, eu já li a documentação do Discordjs e não encontrei nenhuma dica sobre esse comando, enfim caso queiram que eu seja mais especifico é só pedir aqui, eu acho, aqui esta meu código.

```
  module.exports = (client,msg)=>{ //exportando o client do meu bot e outros comandos
    var jimp = require('jimp'); //npm que eu usei para editar as imagens por javascript

    async function edicao(){ 
      const bolsonaro = await jimp.read('bolsonaro2.jpeg')// imagem que vai servir de base para o meme
      const image = await jimp.read('img.jpg')// imagem que vai ser editada
      
      image.resize(308, 171)
      image.rotate(-1);
      bolsonaro.composite(image, 320,181).write('beta.png')
      msg.reply(``, { files: ["beta.png"] })//resposta para o usuario que chamou pelo comando 
      console.log('Imagem enviada para o Discord')

      .catch(err => {
      console.log('error avatar')
      })
    }
    return edicao();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Na documentação do `discord.js` consta que há uma propriedade `attachments` na mensagem recebida. Você pode, por exemplo, listar as imagens com o código abaixo:

```
mensagem.attachments.each(console.log);
```

---

Se considerarmos que o código que você forneceu está correto (o que acho improvável pois me parece que haviam erros de sincronia), teremos algo similar ao seguinte:

```
const jimp = require('jimp');

const editar = async (anexo) => {
  // imagem que vai servir de base para o meme
  const imgBase = await jimp.read('bolsonaro2.jpeg');
  // imagem que vai ser editada
  const imgAnexo = await jimp.read(anexo.url);
  imgAnexo.resize(308, 171)
  imgAnexo.rotate(-1);
  const resultado = imgBase.composite(image, 320,181);
  const destino = `${anexo.name}-editada.png`;
  await resultado.writeAsync(destino);
  return destino;
};

const analisar = async (mensagem) => {
  const promessas = mensagem
    .attachments
    .map(editar);

  const imgsEditadas = await Promise.all(promessas);

  // resposta para o usuario que chamou pelo comando
  mensagem.reply('', { files: imgsEditadas });
};

module.exports = analisar;
```

Note que na minha alteração apenas a mensagem é necessária como parâmetro, então será necessário alterar no local onde a função é chamada também.

---

> [**`.attachments`**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments)
>
> A collection of attachments in the message - e.g. Pictures - mapped by their ids

Em tradução livre:

> Uma coleção de anexos presentes na mensagem - e.g. Imagens - mapeadas pelos seus ids

Comment: Realmente, parece que o attachments percebe que é uma imagem, e esta até printando as informações dele, mas ele da erro ao tentar editar a imagem, eu acho que ele não pegou diretamente a imagem, apenas o ID, o nome, o link... Alguma sugestão?

Comment: @Muriilo é só usar a propriedade `url` do objeto em questão na função `jimp.read`

Comment: cara como eu colocaria isso em código, sou muito iniciante ainda, desculpa.

Comment: @Muriilo não sei como ser mais claro do que no comentário anterior. Você tem uma parte que lê a imagem e atribui o resultado a uma váriavel (`await jimp.read`). Ao invés de passar o nome da imagem você vai passar o que está no atributo `url` do objeto contido na coleção `attachments`. Para que eu possa te ajudar mais que isso, no mínimo você tem que me informar o resultado do seu `console.log` que coloquei na resposta

Comment: @Muriilo fiz uma edição na minha resposta para tentar dar um exemplo de como o seu código ficaria depois de modificado, mas como você não forneceu um exemplo executável dificilmente vou conseguir ajudar mais que isso.